# Modify colours on certain condition actionscript-3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

I have a large XML file which I have loaded into actionScript, it basically is a interactive infograph that I want the user to be able to distinguish between values which are estimates and projections. Therefore thats why I want to be able to change the "beginfill" colour on this condition.

```
var yearRecord:String = xmlData.recordSet.attribute("year");
if( int(yearRecord) > 2013 )
{...}
```

Here is a basic outline of my XML data, where I want to be able to take the value of the year attribute.

```
<dataset>
<source></source>
<extent></extent>
<scaleFac></scaleFac>
<recordSet year="1982" popTotal="1544545">
<m> //Male
<rd></rd>
<f> //Female
<rd></rd>
```

This is where I declare my bar chart values which I want to change colour when the year is beyond 2013.

```
var mcF:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mcF.age=i;
mcF.popValue=xmlData.recordSet[indexYear].f.rd[i].text();
mcF.name="popF"+i
var mcFGraphics:Graphics = mcF.graphics;
mcFGraphics.beginFill(0x660066,1);
mcFGraphics.drawRect(graphX+mfGap,(graphY-(i*cellHeight))-    
cellHeight,mcF.popValue/scaleValue,cellHeight);
mcFGraphics.endFill()
```

Iam not sure on the correct way to do this and any help would be great.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How do you change the fill when the condition is true. I just tried a trace and nothing happens when the year passes 2013 so my if statement isn't even working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you already have every piece of code you need? You posted them in the question.

```
var mcF:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mcF.age=i;
mcF.popValue=xmlData.recordSet[indexYear].f.rd[i].text();
mcF.name="popF"+i
var mcFGraphics:Graphics = mcF.graphics;
var color:Number = 0x660066;  //default color

var yearRecord:String = xmlData.recordSet.attribute("year");
if( int(yearRecord) > 2013 )
{
    color = 0xFF0000;  //projection color
}

mcFGraphics.beginFill(color,1);  //draw with whatever appropriate color
mcFGraphics.drawRect(graphX+mfGap,(graphY-(i*cellHeight))-    
cellHeight,mcF.popValue/scaleValue,cellHeight);
mcFGraphics.endFill();
```